# Finding the convex hull of m x n matrices

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Given a set of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrices, I would like to find the matrices forming the vertices of their convex hull.

Would this be the same problem as finding the convex hull of  a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m + n}$? ie: Could I simply reshape the matrices into vectors and proceed with known algorithms to find the convex hull, and then convert back into $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$?

PS: Please be kind. I am a engineer with limited experience in this field. If you could point me to any references that could be helpful, I's appreciate it.

Thanks

Edit:

1. My set of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrices is finite and each matrix is discrete.
2. Some additional clarification: I am building this set up one matrix at a time. Each time I have a new matrix, I want to test if the new matrix is contained within the convex hull formed by the matrices already in the set. If it is, then I can ignore it. If it is not in the convex hull, then I add it to the set and extend the convex hull to include the new matrix.

Comment: Even in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the problem seems unclear. Circle is a convex shape. How do you define a vertex for a convex shape like circle? Also, on second paragraph of your question, you talk about finding the convex hull. Do you want to find the vertices given a set or find the convex hull given the vertices?

Comment: This is a hard problem in general even with set of matrices with harmless looking properties.

Comment: stressed out, my set includes a finite number of matricies, so your example of a circle is not relevant to my problem, but is is a good example which illustrates why this a hard problem in general. Regarding the second paragraph, maybe a quick example will help explain. If I have a set of, say, 10 matrices, and 5 of these form the vertices of the convex hull which contains all 10, I want an algorithm that identifies these 5 vertex matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is isomorphic as a vector space to $\mathbb R^{mn}$ (note that that‘s not a plus) via the obvious map (taking all entries), you can indeed do the computation in $\mathbb R^{mn}$.